# problem with entries file in SVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, collabnet

I am trying to make changes in 'entries' file in SVN (by using batch file) from path as **file:///home....** I am changing it to **file:///C:/TRY....** However I am successful in doing so but my entries file is compressed means there are no enter '¶'. And some how when I execute svn info from command prompt its not giving me svn info

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Why do you modify the `entries` file?

Answer (score 1):

Never ever mess with data you don't understand!

You're asking the wrong question! You're asking on how to mess with the entries file, but that's just because you're trying to do something else. Always ask for help with what you're originally have to do, not with the problems you get when you try to do it a certain way - there might be a much better way.

Instead, you should have asked how you can point your working copy to another url.

And for that, there's even a command for it! : `svn switch --relocate`

Answer (score 0):

@Stefan: Thanks...I asked this question because Dir structure is so complex that I was not able to execute svn commands as those dir's didnt had .svn dir...I hope ur getting it.However I got the solution...Batch file reads all the contents makes the string changes and writes it again to svn file however while rewriting it adds CRLF in them and svn files have only LF so when anyone again use svn commands on those files he gets error...So I changed the files using vbscript...Now it works fine